# Why are all metas gray except Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, design, meta

Why are all metas grey except Meta Stack Exchange?
Why was it done so?

Comment: To make this site unreadable :( The fonts are so light it is painful to read

Comment: To sum it all up: because Meta Stack Exchange is not a per-site meta like all others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some reasons behind it:

- It is a governing meta for whole of Stack Exchange network.
- It is a separate site unlike other per site meta sites.
- It has it's own reputation system.
- It doesn't have any parent Q&A site.
- And of course unicorns are shifted here.

Comment: Is Meta.SE the father or elder brother of all the other sites?

Comment: Meta.SE is Washington, DC (or possibly the UN General Assembly); the other metas are the local town hall.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it is because this meta is for all SE sites.